# selectOneMenu change becomes inputText's not writable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In a XHTML page, I am using Primefaces, version 3.5. There, I have a `selectOneMenu`, 2 `inputText`'s that are readonly and other editable `inputText`'s ond other `selectOneMenu`'s. When I change the first `selectOneMenu`, the readonly `inputText`'s values are changed. I must use a `p:ajax` to affect these readony `inputText`'s. However, what is odd, it is not more possible to type or even focus the other editables `inputText`'s after this change. Nevertheless it is possible to change the values of the others `selectOneMenu`'s. Also it is no longer possible to change the focus using the TAB button, even among the `selectOneMenu` components. Only through mouse clicks it is possible change the focus.
The XHMTL code is the following:

```
    <p:panelGrid id="pnlDadosAparelhosArquivo" styleClass="noBorders"
        style="width: 100%;">
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selSubTipo"
                    value="#{boObjetosMB.selectedIdSubtipoObjetoLista}"
                    styleClass="select295" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue=""
                        itemLabel="#{m['label.item.selecione']}" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{boObjetosMB.colSubtiposSim}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="descrSubtipoObjeto descrTipoObjeto" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width: 50%;">
                <!-- Not related -->
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <!-- The disabled inputText's to be affected by selSubTipo changing. -->
        <p:row id="rowSubtipo">
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText value="#{boObjetosMB.descrSubtipoObjeto}"
                    disabled="true" id="descrSubtipoObjeto" styleClass="texto290"
                    style="text-transform: uppercase;" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText value="#{boObjetosMB.descrTipoObjeto}" disabled="true"
                    id="descrTipoObjeto" styleClass="texto290"
                    style="text-transform: uppercase;" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <!-- The disabled inputText's to be *NOT* affected by selSubTipo changing. -->
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="txtNotaFiscal"
                    value="#{boObjetosMB.arquivoObjetos.notafiscal}"
                    styleClass="texto290" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="textQuantidade"
                    value="#{boObjetosMB.objeto.quantidade}" maxlength="8"
                    styleClass="texto290" required="true">
                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

I already verified that in the rendered HTML inputs there is no addition of the readonly or disabled attribute. Actually, they maintain unchanged.

It is like it was added some javascript code that when I focus an input it is immedialety blurred (`onfocus="this.blur()"`).

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Answer (score 0):

You must check the response from the ajax request in the network section of the browser's console. Probably you are getting an exception and you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidMantilla: as you suggested, I saw the ajax response but apparently nothing indicates any exception:

```
<changes>
    <update id="form:descrSubtipoObjeto">
        <![CDATA[
        <input id="form:descrSubtipoObjeto" name="form:descrSubtipoObjeto" type="text" 
            value="Telefone celular" disabled="disabled" style="text-transform: uppercase;" 
            class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled texto290" />
        <script id="form:descrSubtipoObjeto_s" type="text/javascript"><!--
PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_form_descrSubtipoObjeto',{id:'form:descrSubtipoObjeto'});
//--></script>
        ]]>
    </update>
    <update id="form:descrTipoObjeto">
        <![CDATA[
        <input id="form:descrTipoObjeto" name="form:descrTipoObjeto" type="text" 
            value="Telecomunicação" disabled="disabled" style="text-transform: uppercase;" 
            class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled texto290" />
        <script id="form:descrTipoObjeto_s" type="text/javascript">
<!--
PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_form_descrTipoObjeto',{id:'form:descrTipoObjeto'});
//--></script>
        ]]>
    </update>
    <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
        <![CDATA[vFKt6AyMKaC9xPonL64tq0iGsxavgotXF7p2tRUDh/iNY0ONSH6BeAp7RMYstRq6elln1g2GqDwlZEL6ElKAlM+c3HYww/UrMNS41Kbh4QsnGQWu6l61XlbYmSTCNAk2JPDN0EODhIlKAgta]]>
    </update>
</changes>
```